# How do fstrim and BTRFS SSD optimizations work for both SSD's in a RAID1?

Tags: btrfs, ssd, trim, fstrim

First apologies if this has been asked before, but I could not find any link with any combination of keywords.

My question is - How do SSD optimisations work in BTRFS in a RAID1 where both devices are SSDs?

Also fstrim does not seem to pick up /dev/sdb1. See output at the end of this post.

I have /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 (both partitions on SSDs) in a RAID1 configuration. But I see no message for sdb1 in the following dmesg output.

```
pi@testpi:~ $ dmesg | grep btrfs
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic, zoned=no, fsverity=no
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] BTRFS: device label nasdisk_01 devid 1 transid 200 /dev/sdd1 scanned by systemd-udevd (209)
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] BTRFS: device fsid 69f422a2-fea7-424c-886b-f291068dae9f devid 4 transid 73286 /dev/sdb1 scanned by systemd-udevd (205)
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] BTRFS: device fsid 69f422a2-fea7-424c-886b-f291068dae9f devid 3 transid 73286 /dev/sda1 scanned by systemd-udevd (204)
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] BTRFS info (device sdd1): using crc32c (crc32c-generic) checksum algorithm
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] BTRFS info (device sdd1): setting nodatacow, compression disabled
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] BTRFS info (device sdd1): disk space caching is enabled
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] BTRFS info (device sda1): using crc32c (crc32c-generic) checksum algorithm
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:06 2023] BTRFS info (device sda1): disk space caching is enabled
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:07 2023] BTRFS info (device sdd1): enabling ssd optimizations
[Thu Apr 20 00:35:07 2023] BTRFS info (device sda1): enabling ssd optimizations
```

My fstab (partial - non-btrfs entries are removed here) is

```
PARTUUID=9c860f91-01  /mnt/raid1_01 btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime  0       2
PARTUUID=9c860f91-01  /mnt/media    btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,subvol=@media  0       2
PARTUUID=9c860f91-01  /mnt/docker-containers    btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,subvol=@docker-containers  0       2
PARTUUID=9c860f91-01  /mnt/shared-samba    btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,subvol=@shared-samba  0       2
PARTUUID=9c860f91-01  /mnt/shared-onedrive    btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,subvol=@shared-onedrive  0       2
PARTUUID=9c860f91-01  /mnt/docker-containers-databases  btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,subvol=@docker-containers-databases  0       2
PARTUUID=9c860f91-01  /mnt/work     btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,subvol=@work  0       2
```

Output of mount command is as following

```
pi@testpi:~ $ mount | grep btrfs
/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/nasdisk_01 type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,nodatasum,nodatacow,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/docker-containers-databases type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=394,subvol=/@docker-containers-databases)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/shared-samba type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=363,subvol=/@shared-samba)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/shared-onedrive type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=391,subvol=/@shared-onedrive)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/work type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=397,subvol=/@work)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/docker-containers type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=362,subvol=/@docker-containers)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/media type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=398,subvol=/@media)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/raid1_01 type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
```

Output of fstrim which shows that /dev/sdb1 is ignored.

```
pi@testpi:~ $ sudo fstrim -vA
/mnt/nasdisk_01: 2.2 GiB (2363473920 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sdd1
/mnt/raid1_01: 5 GiB (5337776128 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda1
/: 2.9 GiB (3139751936 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sdc2
/boot: 201.8 MiB (211645952 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: You don't need to use `fstrim` for BTRFS, the filesystem has autodection for SSD and will use SSD specific settings in default. You can see the additional mount parameters by using just the `sudo mount` command. `/dev/sdb1` isn't ignored, in BTRFS-RAID, all used devices for RAID are just aliases for the RAID. So if you have a BTRFS-RAID out of 3 devices, like `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1`, it's only a singular BTRFS filesystem and each of the device is able to mount the entire RAID - each device has a complete copy of the RAID configuration saved as BTRFS system data.

Comment: @paladin - Thanks!